# PHP PEAR how to check default directories?

Tags: php, pear

During installation, i saw different default directories for PEAR.

Later on can i list these directories by any command?

pear.conf doesn't help me in figuring out :(

```
$cat /etc/pear.conf
```

PEAR_Config 0.9
a:11:{s:15:"preferred_state";s:6:"stable";s:8:"temp_dir";s:17:"/tmp/pear/install";s:12:"download_dir";s:17:"/tmp/pear/install";s:7:"bin_dir";s:8:"/usr/bin";s:7:"php_dir";s:15:"/usr/share/pear";s:7:"doc_dir";s:9:"/usr/docs";s:8:"data_dir";s:9:"/usr/data";s:7:"cfg_dir";s:8:"/usr/cfg";s:7:"www_dir";s:8:"/usr/www";s:8:"test_dir";s:10:"/usr/tests";s:10:"_*channels";a:3:{s:5:"*_uri";a:0:{}s:11:"doc.php.net";a:0:{}s:12:"pecl.php.net";a:0:{}}}[root@domU-12-31-39-02-2D-FD etc

```
1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : /usr
2. Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
4. Binaries directory                            : /usr/bin
5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /usr/share/pear
6. Documentation directory                       : /usr/docs
7. Data directory                                : /usr/data
8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : /usr/cfg
9. Public Web Files directory                    : /usr/www
10. Tests directory                               : /usr/tests
11. Name of configuration file                    : /etc/pear.conf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already found the location that stores these information. It's stored as object serialization.

```
s:7:"bin_dir";s:8:"/usr/bin"
```

means: String "bin_dir" (aka Binaries directory) String "/usr/bin"

More comfortable is `pear config-show` as stated in the [PEAR Manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.config.php)

```
$ pear config-show
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/share/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/php
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/share/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/share/php/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /build/buildd/php5-5.3.6/pear-build-download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/share/php/test
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/share/php/htdocs
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            2
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pear/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/cb/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear/pear.conf
```